# Cast umbraco @CurrentPage to be used in MVC @Html.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco6

Having a child action like this

```
public ActionResult Summaries(IPublishedContent currentPage)
{
    //...
}
```

I would need to pass from the masterpage the @CurrentPage to it, so I would need to use something like this

```
@Html.Action("Summaries", "Blog", CurrentPage )
```

But as @Html.Action cannot be dispatched dynamically I would need to cast CurrentPage and I'm lost there as then I wouldn't be able to use IPublishedContent but I would need a type to cast to.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child action like this

```
public ActionResult Summaries(umbraco.NodeFactory.Node currentNode)
{
    //...
    var value = node.GetProperty("myProperty");
}
```

Then you could just call you action like this

```
@Html.Action("Summaries", "Blog", umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent())
```

This would give you access to the state of the current node as well as traversing the parents and children of the nodes using things like `node.GetChildNodes()`